# Pushing the data with firebase version 3.0.2. .. error is (in promise) Error: PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission denied(…)

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to push the data in firebase but due to my version 3.4.2. old documentation is not helping me

I am trying like this and getting error like "(in promise) Error: PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission denied(…)"

```
  pushData(){

    var firebase = require("firebase");
    var config = {
        apiKey: "api",
        authDomain: "password",
        databaseURL: "https://pass.firebaseio.com",
        storageBucket: "something.appspot.com",
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);

     var rootRef = firebase.database().ref();
     rootRef.push({ 'user_id': 'fred', 'text': 'Yabba Dabba Doo!' });

}
```

i dont know , how should i push my data.
Thanks

Comment: which line show the error

Comment: var usersRef = ref.child("users");   this one... but i am not sure this is perfect way or not

Comment: In the code that you have posed above, `ref` is not defined anywhere. Where/how is ref defined?

Comment: i dont know, how to define ref.. can you please tell me by defining ref\

Comment: You seem to be mixing and matching code from various sites. I recommend following a single tutorial for the platform that you;re using (which seems to be Firebase Database 3.x). One such a tutorial would be the [Firebase codelab for web](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/#0).

Comment: ok.. thanks man.. i will  look at this..

Comment: i tried some way but now i am facing error like (in promise) Error: PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission denied(…).... i dont know.. whats happing there. can you help me with this

Comment: question is updated now.. thanks

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen  i am waiting for your response. i hope you will help me in this. (Firebase engineer at google).

Comment: You're not authenticated. See https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/#6

Comment: i try to take help from this. but honestly nothing helping me. please tell me more briefly. i am just new to it.  @FrankvanPuffelen.. if you are fine. can you help me on teamviewer. i will be really thankul to you.

Comment: all works .. thanks man ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default rules now have basic security in place.  Simply set read and write to true while in early development.

See [Get Started with Database Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/quickstart)